# Axis is not displaying the first element in the domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here's my code on the **Stacked Area viz**.

```
//ds: Thu Oct 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000
//df: Wed Sep 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 

this.scaleX = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain([ds, df])
    .range([0, this.vizWidth]);

config.xAxis = d3
    .axisBottom(this.scaleX)
    .ticks(12)
    .tickFormat(this.dateFormatter);

 dateFormatter(date: any): any {
   try {
     const d = moment(new Date(date)).format('YYYY MMM');
     console.log(`dateFormatter...`);      // ==> I added this line
     console.log(d);                       // ==> it's not displaying it either           
     return d;
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
 }
```

The domain is the fiscal year, i.e. from October 2019 to September 2020. My bottom axis skips the **first tick**, i.e. **October 2019**. The console.log I added produces this result

```
dateFormatter...
2019 Nov
dateFormatter...
2019 Dec
dateFormatter...
2020 Jan
dateFormatter...
...
...
```

As it appears, October 2019 is just being ignored. I've spent the entire day looking at the documentation why it's skipping the first element, but can't find why.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

D3 axes are dynamically generated, specially axes for time scales. Defining the exact values you want in the ticks is notoriously difficult in time axes and may be tricky sometimes.

For instance, no October, even if the domain starts on 01-Oct:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date("2019-10-01"), new Date("2020-09-01")])
  .range([30, 570]);
const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="100"></svg>
```

To guarantee that you always shows the domain limits, use `tickValues` concatenating the domain array. You can use both values in the domain array or just one:

```
axis.tickValues(scale.ticks().concat(scale.domain()[0]));
```

Where `axis` is your axis generator, and `scale` is your scale.

Here is the result:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date("2019-10-01"), new Date("2020-09-01")])
  .range([50, 550]);
const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickValues(scale.ticks().concat(scale.domain()[0]))(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)").attr("class", "axis"));
d3.selectAll(".axis .tick:last-child text")
  .text(d => d3.timeFormat("%B")(d))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="100"></svg>
```

Finally, pay attention to the fact that since we have no idea how D3 is going to generate that tick, I selected and formatted it to month (in this case, using the `"%B"` specifier).

Comment: funny fact, I'm using now `2019-10-01`, instead of `2019-10-last day of the month` like before. Now, I'm getting the `first` element but not the `latest`.  I tried your code `scale.ticks().concat(scale.domain()[1])`. As you can see, I replaced 0 with 1 to get the maxValue, but nothing is happening.

Comment: @Richard77 I suggest you create a running demo online, so we can check what's happening.